# made from coconut and almonds?

Tags: prepositions

In the following definition of *Almond Joy*, should "from" or "of" be used?

> a type of chocolate bar in the US which is made **from**/**of** coconut and almonds

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

[Acc. to Cambridge Dictionary:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/made-from-made-of-made-out-of-made-with)

> We often use made from when we talk about how something is manufactured:

Here I see the emphasis on the source material.

> We use made of when we talk about the basic material or qualities of something. It has a meaning similar to ‘composed of’:

Here I see the emphasis on the elements, which are still recognizable in the product.

In the case of Almond Joy, I think both are acceptable. Almonds and coconut are certainly source material as well as still recognizable if you break the bar in half.

However, the most appropriate option would be "made with":

> We use made with most often to talk about the ingredients of food and drink:

Especially because almonds and coconut are not the main ingredients (or "source material") but Corn Syrup and Milk Chocolate are.
Of course, if you want to advertise Almond Joy, you wouldn't prefer that option. You would want to insinuate that coconut and almonds are more substantial ingredients.